# Change font color on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple about page that uses JQuery click to change the text and the content of the about body (Instead of creating 3-4 independent pages). What I am trying to do with the 'menu' is simple but for some reason it is not working as expected.

Each menu option click will trigger a JQuery event that will change the text of the body, and change the clicked menu option's color to blue to show that it has been selected.

Right now, the jquery I am trying to apply simply isn't working and color isn't toggling on click.

My JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.about-link').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});​
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bBDk8/6/

Comment: That's how **cascading** style sheets work. It's all about specifity baby ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#about-nav a` css selector has more specificity than `.clicked` so the color is applied from that selector instead of `.clicked`. Raise the specificity by using `#about-nav a.clicked` for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/bBDk8/8/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That solves my color change problem, but I am trying to remove the added class when an alternate menu item is selected.

Comment: @MHZ You should mention that in your post, but I can do that: http://jsfiddle.net/bBDk8/12/

Comment: Brilliant! :) Sorry, I misunderstood how toggleClass works and thought it would accomplish that (first time using it). Thank you!

Comment: Last question: #about-nav a.clicked can you explain how this works? I have never seen anything like that before, #about-nav a selects all '<a>' children but what does adding the '.clicked' do? ...it basically creates a .class that is specific to the #about-nav a children?

Comment: @MHZ it's a selector that affects all `a` elements under `#about-nav` that have class `clicked`.